OpenGl to Visualize images
I am trying to use opengl to visualize a image with 16 bits depth because with GTK i was limited to 8 bits. GdkPixbuf has limitations and i need represent the image with all values without changes. I was testing OpenGL and i follow a  basic tutorial for create a shader a texture and put a image. My problem comes with i try to put a 16 bits image (TIFF format) i create that image from DICOM and i want represent but i dont understand if is because i dont have alpha channel or what or simply because i am doing something bad to put image on texture.
I am using the tutorial: https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Textures
but my output is

With other images like jpgs work, i dont understand if my image created by me in other code dont have some parameter or if you want use a greyscaled image on a texture you must put other values on glTexImage2D but i think that i need a alpha channel? for represent in GL_RGB or GL_RGB16. Because in GL_RGB16 the texture is black totally black and in RGB is deformed so i need some tips or help because i am without ideas.
try:
    from OpenGL.GL import *
    from glfw.GLFW import *

    from glfw import _GLFWwindow as GLFWwindow

    from PIL import Image
    import cv2
    import numpy as np

    import glm
except ImportError:
    import requirements

    from OpenGL.GL import *
    from glfw.GLFW import *

    from glfw import _GLFWwindow as GLFWwindow

    from PIL import Image
    import cv2
    import numpy as np

    import glm

from shader_s import Shader

import platform, ctypes

# settings
SCR_WIDTH = 800
SCR_HEIGHT = 600


def main() -> int:
    # glfw: initialize and configure
    # ------------------------------
    glfwInit()
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3)
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3)
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE)

    if (platform.system() == "Darwin"):  # APPLE
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE)

    # glfw window creation
    # --------------------
    window = glfwCreateWindow(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, "LearnOpenGL", None, None)
    if (window == None):
        print("Failed to create GLFW window")
        glfwTerminate()
        return -1

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window)
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback)

    # build and compile our shader zprogram
    # ------------------------------------
    ourShader = Shader("4.1.texture.vs", "4.1.texture.fs")

    # set up vertex data (and buffer(s)) and configure vertex attributes
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------
    vertices = glm.array(glm.float32,
                         # positions          # colors           # texture coords
                         0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0,  # top right
                         0.5, -0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,  # bottom right
                         -0.5, -0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,  # bottom left
                         -0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0  # top left
                         )

    indices = glm.array(glm.uint32,
                        0, 1, 3,  # first triangle
                        1, 2, 3  # second triangle
                        )

    VAO = glGenVertexArrays(1)
    VBO = glGenBuffers(1)
    EBO = glGenBuffers(1)

    glBindVertexArray(VAO)

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO)
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.nbytes, vertices.ptr, GL_STATIC_DRAW)

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO)
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices.nbytes, indices.ptr, GL_STATIC_DRAW)

    # position attribute
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * glm.sizeof(glm.float32), None)
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)
    # color attribute
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * glm.sizeof(glm.float32),
                          ctypes.c_void_p(3 * glm.sizeof(glm.float32)))
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1)
    # texture coord attribute
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * glm.sizeof(glm.float32),
                          ctypes.c_void_p(6 * glm.sizeof(glm.float32)))
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2)

    # load and create a texture
    # -------------------------
    texture = glGenTextures(1)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                  texture)  # all upcoming GL_TEXTURE_2D operations now have effect on this texture object
    # set the texture wrapping parameters
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER)  # set texture wrapping to GL_REPEAT (default wrapping method)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER)
    # set texture filtering parameters
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)

    # load image, create texture and generate mipmaps
    try:
        #img = Image.open("/home/rainor/PycharmProjects/tfg/output8.jpg").convert('RGB')
        img = Image.open("/home/rainor/PycharmProjects/tfg/salida/output_image_16_bits_5.tiff")

        print(img.mode) #print I;16
        print(img.getbands())
      
        glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1)
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, img.width, img.height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img.tobytes())
        #glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, format, img.width, img.height, 0, format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img.tobytes())
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D)

        img.close()

    except:
        print("Failed to load texture")

    # render loop
    # -----------
    while (not glfwWindowShouldClose(window)):
        # input
        # -----
        processInput(window)

        # render
        # ------
        glClearColor(0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 1.0)
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)

        # bind Texture
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture)

        # render container
        ourShader.use()
        glBindVertexArray(VAO)
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, None)

        # glfw: swap buffers and poll IO events (keys pressed/released, mouse moved etc.)
        # -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        glfwSwapBuffers(window)
        glfwPollEvents()

    # optional: de-allocate all resources once they've outlived their purpose:
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, (VAO,))
    glDeleteBuffers(1, (VBO,))
    glDeleteBuffers(1, (EBO,))

    # glfw: terminate, clearing all previously allocated GLFW resources.
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------
    glfwTerminate()
    return 0


# process all input: query GLFW whether relevant keys are pressed/released this frame and react accordingly
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def processInput(window: GLFWwindow) -> None:
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS):
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, True)


# glfw: whenever the window size changed (by OS or user resize) this callback function executes
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def framebuffer_size_callback(window: GLFWwindow, width: int, height: int) -> None:
    # make sure the viewport matches the new window dimensions note that width and
    # height will be significantly larger than specified on retina displays.
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height)


main()


do you have a HDR display? does the display driver support HDR? how do you expect to see more than 200-300 shades? humans aren't capable of seeing more than that and most displays are incapable of displaying more than that.

It is a project for the university simply to see if there is an improvement and if I have a screen with HDR and more than 10 bits of depth. I didn't choose the job, it's what I got and I need to know how to do that.

As far as I can see, you are telling OpenGL to upload data in RGB format with one GL_UNSIGNED _BYTE per channel. If you have a 16 bit image, you need to use something else than 8-bit RGB. Which format you need depends on how you want to process the 16-bits in your shader. If you want to display the 16-bits directly, you also need to make sure that you have a default framebuffer that supports this bit depth.

For the backbuffer, check especially GLFW_RED_BITS, GLFW_GREEN_BITS and so on.
